# Input object cannot be bound to any parameters - Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core

I am trying to overwrite the system laungage list in C# using System.Management.Automation and receive the following error. I am using .NetCore 3.1 and Powershell nuget package 7.0 rc. I had the same commands before and it was working fine. Not sure if its a bug in the library or if I am doing something wrong. I create a new language list which is piped into the set command. I need to add the force argument to ensure that the confirmation window is avoided.

{The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.}   System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord

```
  PowerShell c = PowerShell.Create();

            c.AddCommand("New-WinUserLanguageList")
            .AddParameter("Language", inputLanguage.Culture.Name)
            .AddCommand("Set-WinUserLanguageList")
            .Invoke();
```